# Numpy: How to permute array into indices of larger array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of length L with N zeros, and L-N non-zero values. I have another array of length N. I would like to put the values of the shorter array into the positions of the longer array which are zero, keeping them in order. For example, if I had,

$$
L = \, [1,2,3,0,0,4,5,6,0]
$$
$$
N = \, [10,0,20]
$$
I would want,
$$
L' = \, [1,2,3,10,0,4,5,6,20]
$$
I will do this repeatedly with the same $L$ and many different $N$ (all of the same length). What is the best way to accomplish this using Numpy?

Answer (score 1):

```
L[L==0]=N
```

Unless I’m missing something in your question. In numpy the main constraint is that you want to work with built-in array objects as much as possible. But taking a subset of an array, with indices given by a logical array, is a built-in operation so I expect this to be sufficient. This modifies L in-place, so you’ll need to create a copy for every new N.